# Powershell Date Values 1900*01*01

Tags: sql, powershell, import-csv

I have a PS script script which takes the csv file and import the data into the SQL table. In particular, there is a one column 'Deleted Date' which have no value and should be returned as NULL but instead there is a '1900-01-01' value for the column.

I am declaring the 'Deleted Date' column from CSV as $Date = $_.'Deleted Date' and below is my SQL query:

```
$query = "insert into $table (DeletedDate) Values (`'$Date`')"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -database $database -ServerInstance $server -query ""insert into $table (DeletedDate) Values (`'$Date`')"
```

I tried everything but still cannot import date value as NULL because the column is empty

Comment: parse the collection that holds the `$Date` value and replace any `blank/$Null/whitespace-only` with whatever your DB needs to see instead. perhaps `DBNULL`?

Comment: When `$date` is empty, you'll want to insert a literal `NULL` in the insert query (not `''`)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen. This resolves my issue.